# define expression used when querying the model

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to calculate the average rating of a game and order by descending.
In my models.py I have defined a hybrid property

```
class Review(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  rating = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=2, scale=1), index=True)
  body = db.Column(db.String(140))
  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
  game_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('game.id'))

class Game(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = db.Column(db.String(255), index=True, unique=True)
  reviews = db.relationship('Review', backref='game', lazy='dynamic')

  @hybrid_property
  def avg_rating(self):
    total_rating = 0
    reviews = Review.query.filter_by(game_id=self.id).all()
    for review in reviews:
      total_rating += review.rating

    return total_rating / len(reviews)
```

but when I try and query for the average rating in my routes.py

```
games = Game.query.order_by(Game.avg_rating.desc())
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'desc'
```

I probably need to do something like this in my models.py but how?

```
@avg_rating.expression
def avg_rating(cls):
  # what to write here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is described in the sqlalchemy documentation as a [Correlated Subquery Relationship Hybrid](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#correlated-subquery-relationship-hybrid)

This is a pure SqlAlchemy version:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

@avg_rating.expression
def avg_rating(cls):
    return sa.select([sa.func.avg(Review.rating)]).where(Review.game_id == cls.id).label('avg_rating')
```

The flask-sqlalchemy version should look like this (but I don't have it here, so can't be 100% certain):

```
@avg_rating.expression
def avg_rating(cls):
    return db.select([db.func.avg(Review.rating)]).where(Review.game_id == cls.id).label('avg_rating')
```